# How to detect OpenMP pragmas in llvm /clang

Tags: clang, llvm, openmp

I'm trying to work on transform passes in LLVM aimed at every OpenMP parallel section which are mentioned using 'omp pragmas'.

I'm thinking something like: Module level, Function level and basic block level, can I write any passes at a parallel loop level. If yes, any directions on this would be really helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: Why not try to write small openmp program with parallel region, then compile it to llvm IR (`-emit-llvm`), `llvm-dis` it and view, where was the interior of parallel section. I think there will be some hints like special names...

Answer (score -1):

There is an open source Implementation of OpenMP support in clang in clang-omp.github.com. It uses Intel's libiomp5 which can be downloaded from openmp.llvm.org

Comment: This is not an answer.  I suppose you may have posted it as an answer because you don't have the rep to comment, but the rep limits are imposed for a reason and trying to circumvent them will be both futile and damaging to your rep.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).